# How to add a extra field in todo application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

How to add a extra field in todo application created using Play framework using Scala? I am using anorm DB... I am getting an error named `"not found: value Task"` in `Application.scala` at line 24. I have tried it out, please point out my mistake. Thanks in advance!

**`task.scala`:**

```
package models

import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current


case class Task(id: Long, label: String, name: String)

object Task {
  val task = {
    get[Long]("id") ~ 
    get[String]("label") ~ 
    get[String]("name") map {
      case label~name => Task(id, name)
      case id~label => Task(id, label)
    }
  }

  def all(): List[Task] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("select * from task").as(task *)
  }
  def create(task: Task): Unit= {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      SQL("insert into task (label,name) values ({label},{name})").on(
        'label -> label,
        'name  -> name
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }

  def delete(id: Long) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      SQL("delete from task where id = {id}").on(
        'id -> id
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
}
```

**`application.scala` (controller class):**

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{tuple,nonEmptyText}
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import anorm.NotAssigned

import models.Task

object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Redirect(routes.Application.tasks)
  }
  val taskForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "label" -> nonEmptyText,
      "name" -> nonEmptyText
    )
  )

  def tasks = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(Task.all(), taskForm))
  }
  def showTask= Action {
    Ok(views.html.test(Task.all(), taskForm))
  }

  def newTask = Action { implicit request =>
    taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all(), errors)),
      {
        case (label, name) => {
          Task.create(Task(NotAssigned, label, name))
          Redirect(routes.Application.showTask)
        }
      }
    )
  }

  def deleteTask(id: Long) = Action {
    Task.delete(id)
    Redirect(routes.Application.showTask)
  }
}
```

**Index (view file):**

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[(String, String)])

@import helper._

<h2>Add a new task</h2>

@form(routes.Application.newTask) {

  @inputText(taskForm("label")) 
  @inputText(taskForm("name"))

  <input type="submit" value="Create">
}
```

**`test.html` (view file 2):**

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[(String,String)])

@import helper._

@main("Todo list") {
  <h1>@tasks.size task(s)</h1>

  <ul>
    @tasks.map { task =>
      <li>
        <b>@task.label</b>
        <b>@task.name</b>

        @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id)) {
          <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        }
      </li>
    }
  </ul>  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use :

(apply) and (unapply)

methods properly for form element.

```
(Task.apply)(Task.unapply)
```

Answer (score 0):

`import models.Task._` imports all the methods on the companion object `models.Task` into the current scope, not the `Task` class and object themselves. So the current code would allow you to just call `all` and it would refer to `Task.all`

Change the import to `import models.Task` to instead get Task into the scope in your Application object and you will be able to use the task methods like you are trying to.

Comment: if i change the import its returning the following error type mismatch; found : play.api.data.Form[(String, String)] required: play.api.data.Form[String]

Comment: That means that in your index.scala.html template parameter list you have said that your template takes a Form[String] but you are giving it your taskForm which is a Form[(String, String)]

Comment: Considering these problems you are having I would recommend you to go read a Scala for beginners tutorial of some kind first instead of trying to learn both Scala and Play at the same time.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i made changes as you said , changed my parameters in the view file ..after completing those at the final stage i am getting error in the controller case class as follow, type mismatch; found : anorm.NotAssigned.type required: Long